# CKEditor removes CRLF

Tags: ckeditor, markdown, newline

I'm using CKEditor 4.7.
Some of my contents are HTML, some are Markdown.
For Markdown, I would like to keep CRLF chars.
Here is a text sample :

[image]

This is the result in CKEditor, everything is on one line :

[image]

In CKEditor code, I tried to print the result of `editor.getSnapshot()` and the raw text keeps CRLF.
In configuration, I printed too property `lineBreakChars` from `writer` object, and it seams correct.

[image]

I also already tested to delete all \r\n or 0D0A regex in ckeditor library, but it does not work.

Is there an option to keep to keep CRLF chars ?

Comment: why would you use ckeditor for markdown..?! 

Comment: My client would like to have the possibility to use wysiwyg or markdown editor. Because there is old contents (about 20 000), and they want to create new contents in markdown. I tried to convert all HTML in Markdown. It's not possible. The HTML is too dirty. There is a big risk to break all existant content. By the way, I use Markdown plugin with CKEditor, which is great. But I noticed that CKEditor clean the text, even without Markdown plugin.

Comment: In markdown use double space at the end of a line to render a new line. See if that works for you

Comment: You misunderstand the concept. CKEditor expects / produces HTML all the time. Even you can preserve line breaks and indents, output will be an HTML fragment. That's what CKEditor does. With the `markdown` plugin that you said you use, you cannot initialize CKEditor from a markdown string.  That plugin simply allows you to edit **HTML** content using markdown language, that's it.

Comment: Is all that you want to do is to keep the the CRLF?  That is, you are not expecting the CKEditor to render the markdown.  Is that correct?

Comment: try this .. https://ckeditor.com/addon/markdown